# Is this code implying a latch and unsafe (verilog)?

Tags: fpga, verilog, latch

I am getting started with verilog and I wrote this code here to test if a number if prime.  I know it could be a lot more efficient but it is just for practice.  The way test for primeness is when the reset signal gets sent I initialize the register div to 2.  I then increment it by 1 each clock cycle while it is not divisible by the number I am testing.  Once it becomes divisible (in this case it is either a factor where the number is not prime or the number in which case it is prime) I want to keep the register at the same value.  This is the issue.  Am I implying a latch here. I know that I am assigning a value to div in each branch of the if statement but I am not sure if I should be assigning it to itself.

```
module prime(
    input [31:0] n,
    input clk,
    input reset,
    output done,
    output is_prime);

    reg [32:0] div;
    assign is_prime = div == n;
    assign done = n % div == 0;

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if(reset) begin
            div <= 2;
        end     
        else if(n % div == 0) begin
            div <= div; //does this cause a latch
        end
        else begin
            div <= div + 1;
        end
    end


endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no latch inferred at all. It is simply a flip-flop (well several) with either a clock enable, or a multiplexer of its own output and some other input.

A latch would be inferred if it was asynchronous logic - i.e. you had no clock. In that situation you *may* indeed have a latch as the asynchronous logic would need to hold its value (in this case, if it was async, I think there would have been).

If you are using synthesis tools like Altera Quartus or Xilinx ISE, they generally include RTL netlist viewers which give you an approximate idea of what you are inferring. Below is what your code produces. Note the mux (gets called div~[32..0] by the synthesis tool) on which one of the inputs is the current value of the register.

[image: Inferred Logic]

---

As an aside, and while I am well aware your example is just practicing, it is worth noting that division and modulo require massive amounts of logic to implement and as such are either very slow or need lots of pipelining. The are not operations well suited to FPGAs. There are ways of doing primality tests that don't require the modulo operation which may be better suited to the FPGA.

In case you are curious, and just for the fun of it I compiled the code targeting a Stratix V device (which are one of Altera's to end FPGAs), and the tools report that the design could only run at a whopping 21MHz - without the modulo, it could probably run at upwards of 300MHz :).

Comment: So if it is synchronized on the clock do I not need to worry about assigning div on every branch of the if statement.  Also I know this code is horribly inefficient.  I am just getting some verilog practice, it isnt meant for anything practical.

Comment: @chasep255 correct. Because everything is synchronous, you can safely use them to store values, with no need to worry about a register keeping the same state (think of any clocked register essentially as a 1bit memory).

Comment: Do you know how to simplify the schematic view in vivado?  By that I mean get blocks for modulus and = instead of a bunch of circuits?

Comment: @chasep255 there isn't really a simple way. You can make modules for standard operations like add, equals, muxes, etc, which have parameters for signal widths, etc. The RTL viewer would simply show the module as a box, so it would declutter the display a bit.

Comment: I can see why the % is bad in the massive schematic it generated.  Thanks for all your help.